# CodeIgniter Bootstrap form-horizontal in modal in not working

Tags: css, codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap

My web application uses CodeIgniter framework and Bootstrap 3.0 and I am trying to display a form in my modal. I would like the `labels` to be on the same line as the `input fields` but adding `form-horizontal` to `form` or `modal-body` didn't seem to help.

Code segment below:-

```
<!-- Add Customer Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="addCustomer" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Add Customer</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <?php echo form_open('customer_data/add_customer', ['class'=>'form-horizontal']); ?>

        <?php echo form_label('Name: ', 'name'); ?>
        <?php echo form_input(['name'=>'name', 'id'=>'name', 'class'=>'form-control']); ?>

        <?php echo form_label('Mobile: ', 'mobileNum'); ?>
        <?php echo form_input(['name'=>'mobileNum', 'id'=>'mobileNum', 'class'=>'form-control']); ?>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Add Customer</button>
      </div>
      <?php echo form_close(); ?>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed some function

```
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

or try this:

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addCustomer">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="addCustomer" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <!--form horizontal-->

        <?php echo form_open('customer_data/add_customer', array('class'=>'form-horizontal')); ?>

        <?php echo form_label('Name: ', 'name'); ?>
        <?php echo form_input(array('name'=>'name', 'id'=>'name', 'class'=>'form-control')); ?>

        <?php echo form_label('Mobile: ', 'mobileNum'); ?>
        <?php echo form_input(array('name'=>'mobileNum', 'id'=>'mobileNum', 'class'=>'form-control')); ?>
        <?php echo form_close();?>
        <!--end form-->
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: added that in but didnt seem to make a difference. :(

Comment: i usually use an array of classes with `array('class'=>'form-horizontal')`

Comment: I did that too with `<?php echo form_open('customer_data/add_customer', ['class'=>'form-horizontal']); ?>`. I also tried your method but it made no difference. Trying to add `form-horizontal` into the CSS at `div`s using Chrome Inspector didnt help either.

Comment: do you have make form helper enabled? `$autoload['helper'] = array('form');` at file `application/config/autoload.php`.

try using attribute `array('class'=>'classname')` not `['class'=>'classname']`

Comment: yes I enabled form helper in my view file with `<?php $this->load->helper('form'); ?>` changed to `array('class'=>'classname')` like you advised too but didnt work too.